# Receive Pipeline failure

Tags: biztalk, pipeline, biztalk-2010

I am developing a custom application which directly submits the message to biztalk using submit direct adapter. I am using a passthru pipeline, but the message gets suspended and i am receiving the following error:

> There was a failure executing the
>   receive pipeline:
>   "Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.PassThruReceive,
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines,
>   Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
>   Source: "Unknown " Receive Port:
>   "RP_DCMS_REQ" URI: "CH222001-1200"
>   Reason: Type
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef and the
>   types derived from it (such as
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef) are
>   not permitted to be deserialized at
>   this security level.

I have already set the TypeFilterAttribute=full in the config file. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to actually set `TypeFilterAttribute=full` in your BizTalk config file (BTSNTSvc.exe.config) as well. You can find an example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560795(v=bts.70).aspx.